# Как нарисовать гексагон средствами css?

Tags: css3, html5

Нужно нарисовать гексагон, внутри которого будут указаны контакты. Круг сделать легко - через `border-radius`, а как сделать гексагон?

Comment: Изображения, svg, canvas, clip-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1 (c использованием псевдоэлементов):

```css
.hexagon {
    width: 110px;
    height: 62px;
    background: #fe635e;
    color:#fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 62px;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.hexagon:before { 
 top: -28px;  
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 28px solid #fe635e;
}
.hexagon:after {
 bottom: -28px; 
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-top: 28px solid #fe635e;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">hexagon</div>
```

Вариант 2 (с использованием [clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)):

```css
.hexagon {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background: #fe635e;
    color:#fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 110px;
  
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%);
clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">hexagon</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.hexagon{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```